# Trying to check for internet connection by trying to connect to internet in android

Tags: java, android

I have working on my code for lots of hours and I could not figure out, what is wrong there.

I have a simple class `TwitterActivity`. Inside it I have also a `mSignin` button. I set event handling for `mSignin` button and inside its `onClick(..)` method I call an inner class named `CheckInternetConnection` which extends `AsyncTasck`.

Then in `doInBackground(...)` method I try to get an response code by opening a connection to `"http://www.google.com"`.

As a result I always get IOexception. I tried it with different `ConnectTimeout` and different website, but nothing changed.

What might be going wrong here? Thanks.

```
public class TwitterActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = null;

    private Button mSignin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);

        mSignin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_id);
        mSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                new CheckInternetConnection().execute();
            }   
        });

    } 

    class CheckInternetConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
        @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(result)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
             if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                  try {
                      HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL( "http://www.google.com"    ).openConnection());
                      urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                      urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                      urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
                      urlc.connect();
                      return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
                  }
                } else {
                  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
                }
                return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.bledi.android.twittertest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="TwitterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SearchTwitter"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="com.bledi.TwitterTest"  />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2**

If anyone will come across with the same problem, **DON'T** forget to try it in a real Device. The emulator sometime sucks and you have no idea why.

Comment: Did you update your manifest?
You should have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your XML file.

Comment: yeah of course I did.

Comment: And what is url of your HttpURLConnection? Don't see it.

Comment: oops sorry I will add it. It is "http://www.google.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check if you have internet connection you can use your `isNetworkAvailable()` , with `activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()`. It's enough to validate the availability of internet.

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

If you really want to ping http://www.google.com try this :

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL( "http://www.google.com"    ).openConnection());
            urlc.connect();
            int resp = urlc.getResponseCode(); 
            return resp == 200;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DD", "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("DD", "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I also thought so but its not true. That method will give you only the information whether there is some connection. But in order to prove that there is really internet connection you need to connect to  some servers to test it

Comment: My dear friend this is the same code with mine. Nothing changes

Comment: I removed 3 lines     urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                      urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                      urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);

Comment: Yeah I know it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: Works for me, I received the 200 code invoking this method. So it seems that your issue is not a coding one. Could you post your manifest ?

Comment: the difference is `return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();`

Comment: I tried with your activity code and your manifest, its works, no IOException got the 200 code!

Comment: I tried it with `return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();`. Nothing changes again :(

Comment: But how is it possible that I get IOException. I am going crazy now

Comment: May be a stupid question but : are you sure that you have connection, no sim card without credit or wifi router down :-) ??? All of this is straightforward and without surprise...

Comment: A pleasure... I was always trying on a physical device. Be careful with the emulator when you are playing with the real world...

Comment: Yeah me too. You know only for these case I was lazy to try it in the device. I wish you could have told since in the beginning :D.